# How to use multiple >,<,<=,>= condition in single query with where clause in Pentaho Report Desinger?

Tags: mysql, parameters, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I did like this but this didn't work ??

where (
(LoanAmt>${select_Amt}) or

(LoanAmt < ${select_Amt}) or

(LoanAmt <= ${select_Amt}) or

(LoanAmt >= ${select_Amt}))

Answer (score 0):

Or, And, etc. are also functions in PRD (see Open Formula for documentation).

So what you need to implement is something like

```
OR( condition1 ; condition2 ; ... )
```

I presume you are not trying to implement the exact logic you've written, as that condition obviously always evaluates to true.